# Java - Create a wizard-like interface

Tags: java, user-interface, wizard

I have an assignment to simulate a technology store. The requirement is to have a Java-based GUI for it, and I decided to try and write a wizard-like interface for my application. The problem is, I don't know where to start and what to focus on.

I've looked at:

- AWT/Swing; and
- JavaFX;

But am still very confused since I have not programmed a GUI before. Any suggestions?

Comment: See the [Java Swing Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/).

Comment: http://rakeshmenonp.wordpress.com/2010/03/23/javafx-wizard-ui/

Comment: [SWT Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/SWT/article.html)

Comment: I would recommend API `swings` and use of an IDE like `netbeans`. Gear up , lots of work to do. :-)

Answer (score 2):

In java often the learning curve can simply be knowing the GUI, perhaps it would be best to look at some pre created GUI's first. If you build a GUI with the NetBeans GUI swing GUI builder http://netbeans.org/features/java/swing.html then it will produce the code in java for the GUI, you can edit this and simply learn from the way GUI's swing uses widgets or make the whole GUI in NetBeans. Though I wouldn't have imagined the latter being acceptable for an assignment.

Answer (score 0):

I would use Swing modal Dialogs:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html

They are quite easy to use, and being modal it is easy to implement a series of steps, typical for a wizard.

Another possible implementation is using swing Tabbed panels:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tabbedpane.html

useful especially if you want to indicate to the user how many steps compose the wizard.